# Rails save object to cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, cookies

How can I serialize an array or an object and then save it into a cookie?

```
cookies[:mydata] = serialize({
  :key1 => 'tralala',
  :key2 => 'hahaha'
})
```

Thx!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The recent rails vulnerabilities (especially the one involving rack), made me question how safe was the `Marshal.load` approach I initially recommended.

Please don't use is, as it's dangerous and [may potentially allow remote code execution](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7759). I've removed it from this answer.

While not as flexible the following should work as well:

**Initial object:**

```
my_object = {:k1 => 'v1', :k2 => 'v2'}
```

**Saving:**

```
cookies[:my_data] = { 
  :value => my_object.to_json, 
  :expires => 4.years.from_now
}
```

**Reading:**

```
my_object = JSON.parse(cookies[:my_data])
```